# What program displays volume/screen brightness under KDE?

Tags: kde, power-management, notifications, brightness

It seems there's some bug in KDE related to power management and after putting my netbook to sleep several times, plugging it in and out, the notification about screen brightness set to 100% doesn't want to vanish (and as I modify brightness through keys, another one spawns right on top of the previous one, both half-transparent, two sets of numbers).

Now, I could just kill the superfluous process if I ever knew how it's named. The notification, being an overlay, is "transparent" to 'xwininfo' and the likes. There's a tad too many processes I don't know to start killing by trial and error. Sure restarting X would help but I'd like to get by without reopening my sessions in everything I have open. Once I know what to kill/restart I should be able to solve it (and if I can't restart it, so be it, better no brightness indicator than one stuck!)

So, what's the name of the process that displays this: ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't know how to fix it, but do know how to work around making the screen worse when fixing it. Maybe the following will provide some clues as to how to find the culprit.

Here's my script for getting/setting the backlight value.

I also use KDE and have a slightly less annoying problem. Every time I come back from screensaver/screen off, the display is at brightness 1 (the lowest) which is not what I want.

I wrote the script, copied it into /usr/bin and added an icon to my taskbar to launch it. I use it multiple times a day. The command the icon runs is

```
kdesudo -- /usr/bin/backlight 5
```

and I added the line

```
bigbird ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/backlight
```

to /etc/sudoers so it doesn't ask for a password.

Script:
    http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54584985/backlight

I don't know how to do it, but if you can watch for who changes the "field" in /proc, maybe you'll be a step closer to finding the culprit.

Comment: Recently upgraded from Precise to Trusty. The bug with brightness levels not being restored when the screen turns on again appears to be fixed.